# Does Slick support changing the schema dynamically per query?

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

I want to use postgresql to support a multi-tenant environment, so each customer will have its own schema.

When I make a sql query, can I change the schema dynamically when using Slick?

If so, how?

Comment: I assume you're trying to avoid running a manual `SET search_path = ...` query ?

Comment: @CraigRinger Yes, I don't want to do that on each query.

Comment: You might have to enhance the framework you're using to support that, if it doesn't already.

Answer (score 6):

You can parameterize your Table classes and TableQuery factories.

```
trait Schema{
  def name: String
}
case object Customer1 extends Schema{
  def name = "CUSTOMER_1"
}
case object Customer2 extends Schema{
  def name = "CUSTOMER_2"
}
class MyTable(tag: Tag, schema: Option[String]) extends Table[...](tag, schema){
  ...
}

def myTable(schema: Schema) = new TableQuery( new MyTable(_,Some(schema.name)) )

myTable(Customer1).filter(_.id == 5).run
```

Comment: I need to pass in the schema like a parameter, I will have hundreds of customers and schemas.

Comment: Like this? `def myTable(schema: String) = new TableQuery( new MyTable(_,Some(schema)) );
myTable("CUSTOMER_1").filter(_.id == 5).run`

Comment: I'm also interested in doing this, but would rather not pass the schema all the way down the call stack from the Controller where I derive the schema to use. Would rather not use implicits for this. Any ideas?  Would love to provide a request-scoped MyTable object that the db layer injects when it needs a Table object. @loyalflow did you figure this out?

Comment: You can make your db layer a class and pass the schema in as an argument if that help. Explicitly passing it into methods or constructors is better than some magical dynamic injection.